# не могу составить sql запрос

Tags: sql

Для каждого месяца, когда по сравнению с предыдущем месяцем постов (вопросов и ответов) стало меньше, вывести год, месяц и процент снижения.
Например, в прошлом месяце было 200 постов, а в этом — 100. Снижение на 50%.

http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Помогите, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А с какой целью интересуетесь ? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select mm,cnt as curr,prev,round(100-cnt*100.00/prev,2) prc
  from (
   select mm,cnt,lag(cnt) over (order by mm) prev
     from (
      select year(creationDate)*100+month(creationDate) as mm,
             count(1) as cnt
        from posts
       where PostTypeId between 1 and 2
       group by year(creationDate)*100+month(creationDate)
   ) A
  ) A
 where cnt < prev
 order by mm
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!